# How can I jam cell phone communications with gnu radio and hackrf?

Tags: gnuradio, hackrf

I need to make this project, plase help me with some ideas

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  I don't think I understand.  A [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) is a physical enclosure, GNU Radio is a software development kit, and HackRF One is a software-defined radio device meant to be connected to a computer.  Unless I misunderstand what you mean by a Faraday cage, I don't see how you could use software to make a physical enclosure.

Comment: Hi Anda! At first glance, this doesn't appear to be related to amateur radio which means it probably doesn't fit in here... but it's also very unclear what you are attempting to accomplish and why. After you have a better description, you might consider posting your question at the [Electrical Engineering site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hello, my mistake! I don t want to make an physical Faraday cake. I want to jamming the mobile communications during exam test.  and I thought the classroom would be like a *faraday cage*.

Comment: Since cellphone jamming is illegal and questions about it are not allowed on this forum, I am closing this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking how to do something illegal, and it's off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to put your phone and a small SDR in a faraday cage together such that the SDR only receives the phone’s emissions? If so, a metal lunch box should work for everything except the power and data cables. Heavy RF choking of the cables just outside the box entry would take care of common mode current but you may face other RFI issues from the computer-to-SDR connection you’d have to solve. I hope this helps.

(Hopefully I won’t get downvotes for a best-guess answer to the question as currently stated.)

Comment: Many questions call for best-guess answers.

Comment: I love that someone downvoted me anyway. Classy. :-D

Comment: You were probably downvoted after "Faraday cage" was changed to "jamming".  Not your fault ;)